# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer in java 1.6

Tags: java, hibernate, object, type-conversion

Even I'm casting `Object` into int, but this exception occur...

Actually my Hibernate-JPA method was return `Object` then I'm converting that `Object` into `int`...

Here is my Hibernate code:

```
@Transactional
public Object getAttendanceList(User user){

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select Count(ad) from AttendanceDemo ad inner join ad.attendee at  where at.user=:user",
            Long.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Now I'm converting this `Object` as `int`:

```
int k = (Integer) userService.getAttendanceList(currentUser);
```

I'm converting `Object` to `Integer`.

Comment: Looks like getAttendanceList is returning you Long. Can you post the code for the same

Comment: Are you sure you're returning an Integer? ClassCastException says that you're not returning an Integer...

Comment: Yes.. i want to store getAttendanceList() method return value into k. then only ClassCastException coming and now i'm casting to (Integer) but again that exception come..

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use:

```
((Long) userService.getAttendanceList(currentUser)).intValue();
```

instead.

The `.intValue()` method is defined in class [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29), which `Long` extends.

Comment: But IDE shows... The method intValue() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Why not use `((Number) userService.getAttendanceList(currentUser)).intValue();`

Comment: @johnchen902 yes, that is true... But in this case I am not sure OP really wants that. Or that the db model will change from `Long` to some other numeric type overnight ;)

Comment: oh... thankyou.. fge.. it's working... but when we write like ((Number) userService.getAttendanceList(currentUser)).intValue(); it is not working why???

Comment: @user2496295 uh! That should work... Or do you have another `Number` class which is not the JDK's?

Comment: @user2496295that is not what I meant. Look at your imports. Look at what is the import for `Number`. It should be `java.lang.Number`.

Answer (score 6):

The number of results can (theoretically) be greater than the range of an integer. I would refactor the code and work with the returned long value instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that :

```
int k = Math.toIntExact((Long) userService.getAttendanceList(currentUser));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `long` to `Number`
Remember your database is Number not int or long.